70s or 80s film or TV show with a handgun that fires backwards and a torture chamber that burns the skin off and chars the victims black
I saw only a few minutes when channel surfing as a kid but it stuck with me and I always wondered what it was. One scene involved a group of people chasing an individual through some corridors, but they aren't trying to kill their quarry. The chased person stops and turns around, points their gun at themselves like they're going to commit suicide, and someone in the group says "No, don't!" before being shot out the back of the backwards shooting gun.
The other scene I remember involves people interrogating someone that has been captured and is in some kind of transparent torture chamber sort of like the agonizer booth from Star Trek, except the booth burns the flesh off the victim and leaves them charred and black but still alive. I think their clothes or uniform is fine though.

I always wondered if the "No, don't!" bit was because the person who was shot knew how the gun worked or not.

The backward-firing-gun part sounds a lot like a scene from "The Silencers" (a silly James Bond spoof, starring Dean Martin). I don't recall any torture device though.

There's a James Bond film where Q gives him a gun that fires in the direction the trigger is pulled/pushed. In one scene, the Bond girl points it at herself, the bad guy says something like "no, don't" (can't remember the exact dialogue) and she shoots him though the gun is pointing at her.

@ClaraDíazSanchez After watching that movie the other night isn't so silly as it was played straight.  OTOH Niven's Casino Royal is a different kettle of fish.

It would be really hard to be even remotely accurate in aiming a gun that fires backwards. How in the world would you even do that?

The Reverse Gun is a feature of The Silencers (1966), a "Matt Helm" movie starring Dean Martin.
Gun at IMFDB
The specific scene is seen where the heroine of the piece threatens to commit suicide and shoots her attacker with it. (1h 32m 15s cued up approx below)




I cannot find such a gruesome torture scene but there is a booth (of sorts) where the villain sits and commands lasers.


I just watched this same movie the other night. And the threatened suicide isn't really suicide because she knows that the gun fires backwards, as she has already seen a couple guards dispatched by them not knowing how the gun works.  And the heroine isn't really a "heroine".  She was an enemy agent who ended up help Matt Helm because she realized her organization as going to kill her.

As far as the guard is concerned she is threatening suicide and she is a "heroine" for description only. I could have said, "female protagonist" but that's a tad long-winded.

"pretends to threaten suicide" then. /s

It might be the Matt Helm movie Murderer's Row. (1966)
Dean Martin plays the secret agent and has a gun that shoots back.   This is a super laser beam involved and there is a torture area where the scientist developing the laser is kept.

Murderer's Row has a gun with a 10 second delay as I recall, not a reverse gun.

https://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Murderers%27_Row

That's true but many of the villians are dispatched after pulling the trigger and turning gun backwords which then fires after the countdown killing themsleves.
